# OSX | USB headphone | AudioQueue behavior when device removed

Tags: objective-c, macos, audioqueue

I have set an USB headphone as a Current device to playback and record the audio,

and i am able to get notification when USB headphone gets removed

```
-(void)addListenersForAudioDevices{
    // install kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices notification listener
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress theAddress = { kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster };

    AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &theAddress, AOPropertyListenerProc, self);

}
```

In the notification, i am setting default device as a new Audiodevice, but i am not getting audio on system speaker,

any pointers how to go ahead with it ?

Thanks in advance ...